# Changing ArcGIS Server 10.1 port (6080 to 8080)

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, amazon-ec2

Due some network issue (Maps are not displaying in secure environment), I want to change the default port 6080 to 8080. I am going through Web help and few links in which they mentioned that install ArcGIS web adopter but I do not think that it is recommend for Amazon instance.

We have our ArcGIS Server 10.1 on Amazon instance (windows environment) and I am using the REST link in my Java script applications & sometimes the ArcGIS Port 6080 is blocked due to network permissions and hence my maps are not visible that’s why I need 8080 port

Here are the links I am going through…

Ports used by ArcGIS Server
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Ports_used_by_ArcGIS_Server/015400000537000000/

Deployment scenarios
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000488000000

Amazon configuration for ArcGIS Server 10.1
http://hackgeo.com/arcgis/arcgis-server/arcgis-server-10-1/arcgis-server-10-1-on-ec2-single-server-initial-setup

So any workarounds/suggestions will be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Esri documentation:](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Common_problems_and_solutions/0154000004qt000000/)

> Q. How do I change ArcGIS Server to use a port other than 6080 and a
>   site name other than arcgis?
>
> A.  The recommended way to expose your web services through a
>   different port and site name is to install the ArcGIS Web Adaptor.

If you want to not do what Esri recommend (which could also void your support agreement) you can open this file:

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\tomcat\conf\server.xml
```

And change the port info within the following tag:

```
<Connector maxHttpHeaderSize="65535" connectionTimeout="20000" **port="6080"** protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxPostSize="10485760" redirectPort="6443" server=" "/>
```

I would not do this, as you might get some unexpected behaviour elsewhere.

I would recommend hitting the Elastic IP as opposed to the specific instance name and port number.  Assuming your internal issues are around HTTP on any other port than 80, the Elastic IP will solve this issue.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I will check above settings with my IT admin and let you know soon thanks : )