# I can't find my port 6080

Tags: arcgis-server

[image: My IIS]
[image: My folder arcgis]
[image: CMD]
[image]
I have used `tasklist /svc | find "arc.exe"` in Command Prompt, but
in the services.msc list without arc.exe

Comment: Do you mean 6080?

Comment: http://localhost:6080/arcgis/manager can't acess :(

Comment: Is ArcGIS *Server* installed? Is the service running? Please update the question to include the version of software which has been installed.

Comment: What's service name of arcgis server 10.0? I don't know...

Comment: Open C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\tomcat\conf\server.xml check/change the port. see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48591/changing-arcgis-server-10-1-port-6080-to-8080

Comment: ...\framework\runtime\tomcat\conf\server.xml do not exist.
I can't find Server.xml

Comment: what web adapter are you using? IIS will only work on a Server.Need to know your complete setup and install.

Comment: IIS is already installed.

Comment: You don't need Tomcat or IIS installed to access 6080. Just ArcGIS Server. Verify your setup again and as @Vince said, make sure the service is up and running.

Comment: 10.0 is elderly ("Mature") software.  You should have SP5 and several very necessary patches applied *before* running the post-installer, which actually creates the services.  You might be best off uninstalling, and following the documentation during re-install.

Comment: Is this ArcGIS Server for Java or ArcGIS Server for .NET?